# File manager opens twice in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, filemanager

I have a window of the file manager already opened, and when I click the icon button in the side panel to view that window, another instance of the file manager opens.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Is the first window by chance for an external drive? Such as a separate disk partition or USB drive?

Comment: Yes, it's a separate disk partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has yet to be fixed. You can view the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647). A workaround is to hover over the nautilus icon and use the scroll wheel on the mouse. Or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should also work.